# popup in asp.net on button click or icon(notifications)

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp-classic

in facebook we can see you have 4 friend requests or same like notifications in right side small mail icon,after clicking on it ,pop shows with accept button then it will disappear and remaing three will be shown.

Same thing i need to do in asp.net for purpose of some products approval.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the 'modal pop-up' functionality either with Javascript, or with 'pure CSS'; the latter will work even in case of Javascript disabled. Here is a link to Modal Pop-Up demo implemented as pure CSS3/HTML5 solution (no any javascripting): http://webinfocentral.com/html5/ModalPopUp.htm

Essential part of it utilizes `target` attribute as shown in the listing below:

```
/*** pop-up div to cover entire area ***/
.divModalDialog  {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    /*! important !*/
    display:none;
    /* last attribute set darkness on scale: 0...1.0 */
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    text-align:center;
    z-index:101;
}
/*** ! target attribute does the job ! ***/
.divModalDialog:target  { display:block; }
```

Refer to my article (http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/170049/Pure-HTML-5-CSS-3-Modal-Dialog-Box-no-JavaScript) for the complete solution.